# Will offline videos will be downloaded on all registered devices with same email

Tags: youtube

Actually I have two android devices registered with same google account I added a video to offline in one device will it be downloaded in other device also automatically

Comment: Have you tried it? I guess it's faster to try and get the answer than waiting for the answer, since not all countries are eligible for YouTube offline video support... though my guess is "no".

Answer (score 1):

The simple Answer is NO.

When you download those videos, they are saved in Internal storage of your Android device. The possible location is something similar to below:

> Internal
>   storage/Android/data/com.google.android.youtube/files/Offline/(system
>   generated folder name)/streams

Hence, these downloaded files which are in `.exo` file format are "`local`" to your device.

Secondly, `YouTube` controls access to the offline file.

The permission is controlled on their server per account basis, to access those downloaded files.

`YouTube's` Offline function just saves a copy of a video to your device. This is then not your file and is independent from changes on the original file.

If you delete your on-device data, the original video is not deleted; just your copy.

So, just using same sign-in Google Account don't give you access to local files saved in different devices.